# Set Up Port-Forwarding on Netgear N300 Router

Tags: port-forwarding, remote-access

I have a Netgear N300 router that has DynDNS.org as a preset DDNS option. After setting it up it (unsurprisingly) sent traffic directly to my router. I'm essentially using this to connect remotely to my home (virtual) machine/s.

From what I've read, it seems like I need to set up port forwarding. I tried forwarding "all" inbound traffic to a specific IP but that just didn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Also, I just noticed I get this error after applying the settings:

> "The specified port(s) are being used by other configurations. Please
>   check your configurations of Remote Management, Port forwarding, Port
>   Triggering, UPnP Port Mapping table, RIP, and Internet connection
>   type"

Comment: The error you are seeing is because you are trying to forward a port that is already dedicated to the router itself.  What port(s) are you wanting to forward?  Note that if you have remote management on, then port 80 and probably 443 won't be available for forwarding.

Comment: Thanks, seems kinda obvious now that forwarding all ports wouldn't work. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anyone else has the same issue that I had, I'll post the solution here.

To set it up on a netgear, choose the provider listed (such as dyndns.org) and enter in your account details. If you haven't got an account, go to their website and create one, it's pretty straight forward.

(What this does by the way is automatically update dyndns whenever your IP changes, obviously very helpful if you don't have a static IP and you don't have the ability to check what it is while away from home.)

Once that's done, go to the firewall rules section (for the N300 it's under "content filtering") and select the port you're using and the IP that you want that traffic forwarded to. If you're like me, you won't be able to enter in a custom port in that area, instead you can only select from a list. To enter a custom port you need to go services (also under content filtering) and enter the info there.

Once that's done, go back to the firewall rules, select it from the drop down, enter the IP and you're all good to go! :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I fooled around and by accident I put my port that was not working into port triggering and then I could not use into port forwarding.

So, just

1. Go into port triggering and see if you made anything changes in there. If so, make sure nothing is created in there. Make it look as if it was default.
2. Then try using your port.